# Can someone make their on Web in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web

I’m trying to code my own Web in python. What I mean by this is that I want to create my own version of the internet in python that web browsers connect to. I want to basically create the thing that allows you to browse through websites.

I looked everywhere online but I couldn’t find anything. Can someone help me get started?

Comment: By "I want to create my own version of the internet in python that web browsers connect to" are you talking about [building a webserver with just the python standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877033/how-can-i-create-an-local-webserver-for-my-python-scripts)? By "I want to basically create the thing that allows you to browse through websites" do you mean a web browser in pure Python? Or do you mean build your own networking protocol? All of these topics are exceedingly broad and you probably need to narrow down to something more specific.

Comment: What do you mean by "my own Web"?  Do you mean a _website_, like Facebook or Twitter?  Or do you really mean _the entire internet_?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find some useful things for this

The Python documentation for the http.server module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

The HTTP specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

A tutorial on creating a web server in Python: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_web_programming.htm

A tutorial on creating a web browser in Python: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_gui_programming.htm