# Shutdown socketserver serve_forever() in one-thread Python application

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

I know that socketserver has a method `shutdown()` which causes server to shut down but this only works in multiple threads application since the shutdown needs to be called from different thread than the thread where `serve_forever()` is running.

My application handles only one request at time so I do not use separate threads for handling requests and I am unable to call `shutdown()` because it causes deadlock (it's not in the docs but it's stated directly in the source code of socketserver).

I will paste here a simplified version of my code for better understanding:

```
import socketserver

class TCPServerV4(socketserver.TCPServer):
  address_family = socket.AF_INET
  allow_reuse_address = True

class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
  def handle(self):
    try:
       data = self.request.recv(4096)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       server.shutdown()

server = TCPServerV4((host, port), TCPHandler)
server.server_forever()
```

I am aware that this code is not working. I just wanted to show you the thing I would like to accomplish - to shutdown server and quit the application while waiting for incoming data when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: separate thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-to-stop-basehttpserver-serve-forever-in-a-basehttprequesthandler-subclass

Answer (score 28):

You can start another thread locally, in your handler, and call `shutdown` from there.

Working demo:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import time
import thread

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path.startswith('/kill_server'):
            print "Server is going down, run it again manually!"
            def kill_me_please(server):
                server.shutdown()
            thread.start_new_thread(kill_me_please, (httpd,))
            self.send_error(500)

class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    def server_bind(self):
        import socket
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)

server_address = ('', 8000)
httpd = MyTCPServer(server_address, MyHandler)
try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
httpd.server_close()
```

Few notes:

1. To kill server, do **POST** request to `http://localhost:8000/kill_server`.
2. I create function which calls `server.shutdown()` and run it from another thread to solve the problem we discuss.
3. I use advice from [Binding Socket: “Address already in use”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18858817/774971) to make socket instantly avaliable for reuse (you can run server again without having *[Errno 98] Address already in use* error). With stock TCPServer you will have to wait for connection to timeout to run you server again.

Comment: Why catch KeyboardInterrupt from serve_forever?

Comment: @Jonathan, it was done to free the socket properly using `server_close()`. As a result, you can restart the server without waiting for timeout untill pending connections do actually close. I retested the code, on Python 2.7.3 (Linux) it is already unnecessary. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 19):

The SocketServer library uses some weird ways of handling inherited attributes ( guessing due to use of old style classes).  If you create a server and list it's protected attributes you see:

```
In [4]: server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('127.0.0.1',8000),Handler)
In [5]: server._

server._BaseServer__is_shut_down
server.__init__
server._BaseServer__shutdown_request
server.__module__
server.__doc__
server._handle_request_nonblock
```

If you just add the following in your request handler:

```
self.server._BaseServer__shutdown_request = True
```

The server will shutdown. This does the same thing as calling `server.shutdown()`, just without waiting (and deadlocking the main thread) until it's shutdown.

Comment: Ugly but still the cleanest way I've found :/ The standard library should have a nowait argument so it can be called in the same thread

Answer (score 5):

You should call `shutdown` in other thread actually as pointed in source code:

```
 def shutdown(self):
        """Stops the serve_forever loop.

        Blocks until the loop has finished. This must be called while
        serve_forever() is running in another thread, or it will
        deadlock.
        """
        self.__shutdown_request = True
        self.__is_shut_down.wait()
```

Comment: this is what I found useful. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I believe the OP's intent is to shut down the server from the request handler and I *think* that the `KeyboardInterrupt` aspect of his code is just confusing things.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> from the shell where the server is running *will succeed* in shutting it down without doing anything special. You can't press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> from a different shell and expect it to work, and I think that notion *may* be where this confusing code is coming from. There is no need to handle the `KeyboardInterrupt` in `handle()` as the OP tried, or around `serve_forever()` as another suggested.  If you do neither, it works as expected.

The only trick here -- and it is tricky -- is telling the server to shutdown from the handler without deadlocking.

As the OP explained and showed in his code, he is using a single threaded server, so the user who suggested to shut it down in the "other thread" is not paying attention.

I dug around the `SocketServer` code and discovered that the `BaseServer` class, in its effort to work with the threaded mixins available in this module, actually makes it more difficult to use with non-threaded servers, by using a `threading.Event` around the loop in `serve_forever`.

So, I wrote a modified version of `serve_forever` for single-threaded servers which makes it possible to shut down the server from the request handler.

```
import SocketServer
import socket
import select

class TCPServerV4(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    address_family = socket.AF_INET
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass):
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
        self._shutdown_request = False

    def serve_forever(self, poll_interval=0.5):
        """provide an override that can be shutdown from a request handler.
        The threading code in the BaseSocketServer class prevented this from working
        even for a non-threaded blocking server.
        """
        try:
            while not self._shutdown_request:
                # XXX: Consider using another file descriptor or
                # connecting to the socket to wake this up instead of
                # polling. Polling reduces our responsiveness to a
                # shutdown request and wastes cpu at all other times.
                r, w, e = SocketServer._eintr_retry(select.select, [self], [], [],
                                       poll_interval)
                if self in r:
                    self._handle_request_noblock()
        finally:
            self._shutdown_request = False

class TCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request.recv(4096)
        if data == "shutdown":
            self.server._shutdown_request = True

host = 'localhost'
port = 52000
server = TCPServerV4((host, port), TCPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

If you send the string `'shutdown'` to the server, the server will end its `serve_forever` loop. You can use netcat to test this:

```
printf "shutdown" | nc localhost 52000
```

Comment: I get a => r, w, e = SocketServer._eintr_retry(select.select, [self], [], [],
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_eintr_retry'

Answer (score 4):

I used this in Python 3.7.4

```py
def handle():
    setattr(self.server, '_BaseServer__shutdown_request', True)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` in the TCP handler (or if you re-raise it), it should trickle down to the root call, in this case the `server_forever()` call.

I have not tested this, though. The code would look like this:

```
import socketserver  # Python2: SocketServer

class TCPServerV4(socketserver.TCPServer):
    address_family = socket.AF_INET
    allow_reuse_address = True

class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request.recv(4096)

server = TCPServerV4((host, port), TCPHandler)

try:
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.shutdown()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've already tried something like this. It writes an "exception happend" warning in the terminal and closes the connection (handle method returns) but serve_forver is still waiting for incoming connections and as as soon as one is accepted, application continues normally. To quit the application altogether, I need to press Ctrl-C so the "exception happened" warning appears and then Ctrl-C again before any connection is established.

Comment: I personally think it's not possible and I have only two options: either put handle method in different thread or not to use module socketserver and therefore create server manually (socket,bind,listen etc.)

Comment: seems like for a `http.server.HTTPServer` this simple approach works. If you Ctrl+C the server is properly shutdown from the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try signals:

```py
import signal
import os

# inside handler code that has decided to shutdown:
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGHUP)    # send myself sighup
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem I found with many of the solutions posted is 'server not defined'.  To get around that, save the server handle in the constructor.  That way, a second server is not required to shut down the server.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, ThreadingHTTPServer

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        # Save the server handle
        self.server = server
        BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)

    # This can be do_POST or do_SET, whatever takes your fancy
    def do_GET(self):
        if 'exit' in self.path:
            # Commit suicide
            # Send OK
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
            self.end_headers()
        
            # Tell sender what is happening
            self.wfile.write(bytes('Shutting down server', 'utf-8'))
            # Shut down server
            self.server.shutdown()

# Start server
port_server = ThreadingHTTPServer(('localhost', 5000), Handler)
port_server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this with a non-threaded server. Starting the serve_forever loop in a thread was the only way I was able to get shutdown() to work, also from a different thread (specifically was hitting blocking/deadlocks on the self.__is_shut_down.wait() call mentioned in another answer)

```
class SimpleHttpServerAdapter:
    def init(self):
        self.__httpServer: HTTPServer | None = None

    def start(self):
        print("Starting simple HTTP server on port 8000")

        self.__httpServer = HTTPServer(("localhost", 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

        def start_in_separate_thread(httpServer: HTTPServer | None):
            if httpServer:
                httpServer.serve_forever()

        thread = Thread(target=start_in_separate_thread, args=(self.__httpServer,))
        thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        print("Stopping simple HTTP server")

        def stop_in_separate_thread(httpServer: HTTPServer | None):
            if httpServer:
                httpServer.shutdown()

        thread = Thread(target=stop_in_separate_thread, args=(self.__httpServer,))
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to come up with an http server for a unit testing in C++.

I've used this new code for python 3.x:

```
import os
import signal
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path.startswith('/kill_server'):
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
        else:
            SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

server_address = ('', 1234)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)
try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except Exception:
    httpd.shutdown()
```

Save this script to `my_http_server.py` and invoke the http server:

```
python3 my_http_server.py &
```

From within a browser, kill the server and the process by:

```
http://127.0.0.1:1234/kill_server
```

For me, I had to use this server from C++ unit test code.
I used C++ code to save this script as a string to a temporary file and start the script:

```
system("python3 /tmp/my_http_server.py &");
```

Then on tear down of the unit test, sending a `GET` to `/kill_server` has done the cleanup work.