# How do I shut down a python simpleHTTPserver?

Tags: python, d3.js, simplehttpserver

So I'm trying to learn d3, and the [wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) suggested that

> To view the examples locally, you must have a local web server. Any
>   web server will work; for example you can run Python's built-in
>   server:
>
> `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &`

Great... only now I have a server running... but at some point I think I should probably shut that down again.

Is there a better way of shutting it down than using `kill <pid>`? That seems like kind of a big hammer for a little job.

(I'm running Mac OS 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard))

FWIW: `ctrl+c` gives about 10 lines of traceback, complaining about being interrupted.

`kill -3 <pid>` gives a Finder warning in a separate window 'Python quit unexpectedly'.

The default `kill <pid>` and `kill -15 <pid>` are relatively clean (and simple).

Comment: dont use the `&` and use `ctrl+C` instead :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley is right. I use `SimpleHTTPServer` quite often (even added alias `p` for it). To stop the server, I just press Ctrl+C. Joran, why did you not post that as an answer?

Comment: keyboard interrupt == similarly ugly, besides then it's sitting there in a window. I can do that, I was just hoping there was a slightly more elegant way.

Comment: ^ thats why i didnt post it as an answer ... its not really different than the way she's doing it now

Comment: but I think 99% of people just kill it with `ctrl+c` IRL

Comment: If you're using bash or similar shell, you can all do `fg` then a control-C (if this is the last process put in background).  Or you can do `kill %%` (again, if this is the last process put in background).  You can also specify a number n `kill %n` if you know which job number.  Run `jobs` to list the jobs in background.  Read more about this in the shell man-page.

Comment: from python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570591/how-do-i-kill-simplehttpserver-from-within-a-python-script

Comment: check out this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/38943044/2248627

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are simply sending signals to the processes. `kill` is a command to send those signals.

The keyboard command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT, `kill -9` sends a SIGKILL, and `kill -15` sends a SIGTERM.

What signal do you want to send to your server to end it?

Comment: I'd like to send it whichever signal is appropriate to exit it gracefully without leaving garbage in the system or on my screen. In the case of `ctrl+c`, I get about 10 lines of a traceback complaining that it was interrupted. That looks like pulling the plug without shutting down the system.

Comment: Then you have to catch and manage the reception of that signals, clean the house and exit the program (or not, the python interpreter doesn't close on Ctrl+C). The standard module `signal` might be useful.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1112350/1688590) shows how to implement a simple catcher for SIGINT (Ctrl+C) and exit without "traceback".

Comment: just to add/clarify, `kill` isn't overkill.  it just sends a signal, defaulting to "hey, shut down".  your app can treat the different signals differently. `SIGTERM`, `SIGKILL`, `SIGHUP`, `SIGQUIT` etc can all be sent with `kill`.  you should read up on `kill` and the different types of processes.

Comment: @Jonathan yes, I have just read the man pages. However, I was kinda thinking that python would have something like 'bye' or 'q' for shutting down a  running module. Apparently, I can use the `signals` module to catch one of these and shutdown gracefully, but that doesn't come already packaged with the `SimpleHTTPServer`. So I will probably do as the 99% do.

Comment: `Signal` and `SimpleHTTPServer` are both part of the Python standard library, they come within Python.  killing with `ctl-c` is totally fine , but I personally just send a kill signal because i like using `&`.

Answer (score 42):

if you have started the server with

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
```

then you can press ctrl + c to down the server.

But if you have started the server with

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

or

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 & disown
```

you have to see the list first to kill the process,

run command

```
ps
```

or

```
ps aux | less
```

it will show you some running process like this ..

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
7247 pts/3     00:00:00 python
7360 pts/3     00:00:00 ps
23606 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
```

you can get the PID from here. and kill that process by running this command..

```
kill -9 7247
```

here 7247 is the python id.

Also for some reason if the port still open you can shut down the port with this command

`fuser -k 8888/tcp`

here 8888 is the tcp port opened by python.

Hope its clear now.

Comment: this approach helps avoid unnecessary steps when running the server in the future.

Comment: On MacOS, use `lsof -nti:8888 | xargs kill -9` to free the port, as the `fuser` command does not support the `-k` switch.

Answer (score 20):

```
MYPORT=8888; 
kill -9 `ps -ef |grep SimpleHTTPServer |grep $MYPORT |awk '{print $2}'`
```

That is it!

### Explain command line :

- `ps -ef`  : list all process.
- `grep SimpleHTTPServer` : filter process which belong to "SimpleHTTPServer"
- `grep $MYPORT`   : filter again process belong to "SimpleHTTPServer" where port is MYPORT (.i.e: MYPORT=8888)
- `awk '{print $2}'` : print second column of result which is the PID (Process ID)
- `kill -9 <PID>`  : Force Kill process with the appropriate PID.

Comment: Wow! So simple!

Comment: Thank you for answering the question!

Answer (score 14):

or you can just do `kill %1`, which will kill the first job put in background

Comment: You don't know for sure whether it is the first background job. It doesn't really answer the question, as using 'kill' is already in the question.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that worked for me

Comment: This answer is quite effective. @Reinout it you are unsure maybe with the command "jobs" you can see the background jobs lineup, like:    
    [1]+  Running                 python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &

Answer (score 12):

Turns out there is a shutdown, but this must be initiated from another thread.

This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533929/573216

Comment: Thank you for being the only answer that pointed to a programmatic way of shutting down the server. This should be among the highest voted answers!

Answer (score 5):

When you run a program as a background process (by adding an `&` after it), e.g.:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

If the terminal window is still open you can do:

```
jobs
```

To get a list of all background jobs within the running shell's process.

It could look like this:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

To kill a job, you can either do `kill %1` to kill job "[1]", or do `fg %1` to put the job in the foreground (fg) and then use ctrl-c to kill it. (Simply entering `fg` will put the last backgrounded process in the foreground).

With respect to SimpleHTTPServer it seems `kill %1` is better than `fg` + ctrl-c. At least it doesn't protest with the kill command.

The above has been tested in Mac OS, but as far as I can remember it works just the same in Linux.

**Update:** For this to work, the web server must be started directly from the command line (verbatim the first code snippet). Using a script to start it will put the process out of reach of `jobs`.

Comment: This is the only answer that I can do from the command line with just a few keystrokes, and prevent python spewing tracebacks onto the command line. Thanks!

Comment: Also for those who don't know, if you didn't have the foresight to start `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888` with &, just do Ctrl-Z first to send it the background, then as before run `jobs` to see its number, then `kill %1` to kill it (if it was job 1).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like overkill but you can use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to start and stop your simpleHttpserver, and completely manage it as a service.

Or just run it in the foreground as suggested and kill it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: That does look like a reasonable solution, though a bit more than I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just kill the terminal where you run the command to start the http server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @tphan, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your answer, "kill the terminal" is indeed not yet in the list of answers. I hope you have a good time here.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> once(wait for traceback), then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> again did the trick for me :)

Comment: I'm willing to bet you don't have a terminal `&` in your command. ctrl-c does nothing with the ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.

Suppose You have started the server using this command -

```
python3 -m http.server 7800
```

To kill that process use -

```
pkill -9 -f  'python3 -m http.server 7800
```

That's it.