# How can I exit SimpleHTTPServer without closing terminal?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I am running the SimpleHTTPServer from powershell.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

I want to exit (control + break) the server without closing the terminal.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Check that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647196/how-do-i-shut-down-a-python-simplehttpserver

Comment: If you are using powershell 3, use the PSSession cmdlets to run it in a background, and control the parent process.

Comment: Here's another alternative. Ctrl Z: [http://superuser.com/a/262948](http://superuser.com/a/262948)

Comment: You can see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647196/how-do-i-shut-down-a-python-simplehttpserver/31334292#answer-31334292 in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

^C will close it (control + c)

Example of me testing control + c to send an interupt and exit:

```
PS C:\> python -m http.server 8080
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 ...

Keyboard interrupt received, exiting.
```

Note, I am using http.server as this replaces SimpleHTTPServer in Python 3 but it should work the same for you.