# How to gracefully shutdown python SimpleHTTPServer in ubuntu?

Tags: python, web-deployment, simplehttpserver

I started the server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

I am a complete beginner to web development and was using Python SimpleHTTPServer 2.7 in ubuntu. While trying to **shutdown** the server, `ctl + c` gives me a traceback complaining about being interrupted.

After looking at threads:
1. [How do I shut down a python simpleHTTPserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647196/how-do-i-shut-down-a-python-simplehttpserver/12647509)

2. [Shutdown socketserver serve_forever() in one-thread Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085996/shutdown-socketserver-serve-forever-in-one-thread-python-application/22533929#22533929)


3. [Shutting down an HTTPServer](https://blog.gocept.com/2011/08/04/shutting-down-an-httpserver/)

I can understand that it is possible to **properly** (or **gracefully**) **shutdown** the server. But as I am a newbie I am not able to actually do it.

**P.S.:** In the 3<sup>rd</sup> link above. There is also a code to "I think gracefully shutdown the SimpleHTTPServer". But I am also not able to understand - how to run that code?

Please Help
Thank You in advance

Comment: What's exactly the problem with interrupting it through Ctrl-C? It's the regular way to interrupt it, it's not like something gets ruined...

Answer (score 0):

A graceful shutdown is just ending the socket session before you shutdown the server. Basically if you add a try catch to the code that handles the keyboard exception, then under that run a socket shutdown, then you're golden. But add code so we can help better.
edit - spelling and grammar

Comment: I started the server using python -m SimpleHTTPServer

Comment: Now, if I do not do anything and just want to shut down the server including all background processes (if any). Then what shall I do because ctrl + c gives a traceback which spooks me, that some data loss might have occured.

Answer (score 0):

If you have started server like

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
```

Then ctr+c will take server down but if you have stared server like

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

then you will have to kill the process using command

```
ps
```

then you will get running processes like

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
7247 pts/3     00:00:00 python
7360 pts/3     00:00:00 ps
23606 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
```

so just go for kill:

```
kill -9 7247
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply .... ctrl + c gives a traceback which spooks me, that some data loss might have occured ... might be a difference between linux and windows (as I am using ubuntu). Please correct me if I am wrong