# How to stop a server in python?

Tags: python, server, raspberry-pi

I am trying to live-stream using a server and the code after serve_forever() is not running. I am not able to stop live-streaming without using the keyboard interrupt. I need to use python code for stopping the live-stream after a certain time, closing the server and closing the raspberry pi camera. Any help would be appreciated.

```
try: 
    address = ('',8000)
    server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
finally:
    camera.stop_recording()
```

Comment: I don't know the library you are using but suspect you don't want to use `serve_forever()` if you don't want to serve forever. What other methods are available on a `StreamingServer` object?

Comment: one way to do it is use `signals` have a signal handler call `server_close()` when triggered

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-to-stop-basehttpserver-serve-forever-in-a-basehttprequesthandler-subclass) is a similar question, im not sure what kind of server you are using, but this might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The normal method is to call `server.shutdown()`. Simply it cannot be called from the request handler. Long story short: call it from a different thread.