# Run http.server in background (python, not bash)?

Tags: python, python-3.9, socketserver, http.server

I need to start a server on `localhost:3000` when starting python `TestCase` and then close it after `TestCase` finished.

I just realized that `http.server` does not detach the server so after starting the server, the `TestCase` does not continue until the server is not stopped.

```
class ServerTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.server = socketserver.TCPServer(("", 3000), handler)
        cls.server.serve_forever()
        super().setUpClass()

    ... TESTS THAT SEND REQUESTS TO localhost:3000 ...

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.server.server_close()
```

Is it possible to make it work with `http.server`?

Comment: Check out solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-to-stop-basehttpserver-serve-forever-in-a-basehttprequesthandler-subclass

Comment: @matszwecja Nice, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop BaseHTTPServer.serve\_forever() in a BaseHTTPRequestHandler subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-to-stop-basehttpserver-serve-forever-in-a-basehttprequesthandler-subclass)