# Unbind python server

Tags: python, http, server

Here I have some abstract code that I need to work.

```
>>> s0 = Server(port='5000', handle=print)
>>> s0.stop()
>>> # Starting a second server with another port seems OK.
>>> s1 = Server(port='5001', handle=print)
>>> s1.stop()
>>> # This will raise Exception, because port '5000' is still busy by a first server(s0 object).
>>> # I have to exit python process, to release port.
>>> # P.S. deleting an object does not change anything.
>>> s2 = Server(port='5000', handle=print)
```

I've tried Flask.
I've tried SimpleXMLRPCServer:
[How to stop BaseHTTPServer.serve_forever() in a BaseHTTPRequestHandler subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-to-stop-basehttpserver-serve-forever-in-a-basehttprequesthandler-subclass)

Even if it is not raising Exception, the (s2 object) does not accept requests, they are going nowhere, not returning a status or anything.

How can I create a server on port '5000' for example, close this server and create it again when needed. Is it possible with python?

Comment: Seems based on the answer the function to stop seems to be named `shutdown()` not `stop()`

Comment: A particular port number remains blocked for a couple of minutes after the socket was closed, so that late-arriving packets don't confusingly get delivered to an entirely unrelated socket using the same port.  You can disable this by setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` option on the socket; since you're using much higher-level abstractions, I have no idea how (or even *if*) you could get access to the underlying socket to set this option.